# New user has appeared on my Macbook Pro

Tags: malware, macos, xcode

Today I noticed the addition of a new user "Linchengzhang" on my MacBook pro. Apparently the user was added 25th April 2019 (according to the folder creation) and it appears to have an identical structure as those described in this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197210/new-user-with-chinese-name-appeared-on-macos-hacker)and this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317569/somebody-with-chinese-username-hacker-writes-files-into-folder-users-what). I don't know how they managed to structure their files so they could grab all the directory in a screenshot, but if anyone knows and needs to to see it, let me know.

Interestingly, they do not show up in "users and groups", so I don't think they're really classed as a user, but they are placed in the "Users" subdirectory.

As it's mentioned in the first post I've linked I do have to say that this mac has been sent away for repairs to Apple on 8th April 2019.

I do download a lot of software from a lot of places as I'm a bioinformatics student working on many different projects and so I can't rule out that I've downloaded something suspicious. I'm curious as to the fact I haven't noticed it until now, I spend quite a bit of time moving between directories and it's not unusual for me to accidently wind up in the Users directory when I go one or two too far back.

It seems quite suspicious to me (as a non-information security professional) and I was wondering a) what you all think and b) what do I do about it?

Comment: Many software you install will create a corresponding user they run as. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Not that the other question had a satisfying answer, but this seems to have happened to others: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197210/new-user-with-chinese-name-appeared-on-macos-hacker